# adding an integer to a specific number on a line in a text file

Tags: python

The file includes a username surname year membership status nights booked and points

members usernames consist of the first three letters of their surname, plus a three-digit number, followed by the last two digits of the current year

We're currently struggling to find a way to add points to a specific user on a text file.

```
Booking = int(input('How many nights do you want to book:    '))
if Booking <= 14:
    Users = str(input('Have you already signed up as a user:    '))
    if Users == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        Login = str(input('Enter given username    '))
        datafile = open('Users2.txt')
        for line in datafile:
            if Login in line:
                points = Booking * 2500
                NewUser = Login
            else:
```

Comment: any errors or you are just struggling to add the number?

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to use a text file as a database.  if this is a small project, you may want to look into SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite which is very user friendly under python.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Users2.db') #this takes place of Users2.txt

c = conn.cursor()
# THIS ONLY FIRST TIME, JUST EXAMPLE
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE users
             (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,username text, surname text, year text, membership text)''') 
# you can create your structure here

c.execute("INSERT INTO users(id,username) VALUES (1,'farbiondriven')")


conn.commit()
Booking = int(input('How many nights do you want to book:    '))
if Booking <= 14:
    Users = str(input('Have you already signed up as a user:    '))
    if Users == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        Login = str(input('Enter given username    '))

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?', Login)
        outputQuery = c.fetchone()
        if(len(outputQuery)>0):
           ....do your stuff...




conn.close()
```